# Python requests.get does not take field names for data

Tags: python-requests, python-requests-json

I need to generate data using the below url via requests.get :

```
fields = ("")
response_2 = requests.get(BASEURL + 'services/v17.0/report-jobs/' + jobId + "?fields=" +fields , 
headers = header_param)
```

For the purpose of the question, both the BASEURL and the JobID are pre defined.
However, there are several field names in the dataset such as Date, [Agent Name], [Agent ID] etc. that I'm looking to generate.
When I leave the fields object blank, no data is generated.
When I try to define the fields object using

```
fields = ("Date, Agent Name")
```

or

```
fields = ("Date", "Agent Name")
```

I always get back the error : Invalid fields argument

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: What do you want the result to be?

Comment: @Mick   I am coercing the result to a json and then extracting a file url from there.

Comment: Since the fields object above is empty, the data I extract from the url ends up being empty

Comment: I mean how do you want the final url to look

Comment: HTTPS://API-C31.INCONTACT.COM/INCONTACTAPI/services/V20.0/files?fileName=CustomReports%5cApiReports%5cAgent+Login+Time+Details+Daily_20210110T203114.xls   That;s the final url

Comment: That's kind of non-specific, I mean in relation to this url: "BASEURL+'services/v17.0/report-jobs/'+jobId+"?fields="+ fields". What does fields look like in this url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what result you want, but the problem is you're trying to concatenate a string and a tuple, and misusing a tuple.

```
requests.get(BASEURL + 'services/v17.0/report-jobs/' + jobId + "?fields=".join(str(i) for i in fields)
```

Comment: I am seeing the error 404: Invalid or missing JobID. I defined the fields object as fiields = ("Date, Agent Name") and then executed the above get request